# How to check if list elements is the same as SOME of the headings in a df?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, while-loop

I would like to compare a list to the headings of a dataframe, and as long as all of the list elements match with the column headings (but the list does not need to contain all of the column headings), the code would continue, and drop any of the columns which the headings do not match with the list elements. But if some of the list elements don't match with any of the columns headings, it would require the user to enter a new list again. An example is below:

```
import pandas as pd

employees = [('Stuti', 28, 'Varanasi', 20000),
            ('Saumya', 32, 'Delhi', 25000),
            ('Aaditya', 25, 'Mumbai', 40000),
            ('Saumya', 32, 'Delhi', 35000),
            ('Saumya', 32, 'Delhi', 30000),
            ('Saumya', 32, 'Mumbai', 20000),
            ('Aaditya', 40, 'Dehradun', 24000),
            ('Seema', 32, 'Delhi', 70000)
            ]

df = pd.DataFrame(employees, columns=['Name', 'Age','City', 'Salary'], )
df = df.set_index('Name')
print(df)

         Age      City  Salary
Name
Stuti     28  Varanasi   20000
Saumya    32     Delhi   25000
Aaditya   25    Mumbai   40000
Saumya    32     Delhi   35000
Saumya    32     Delhi   30000
Saumya    32    Mumbai   20000
Aaditya   40  Dehradun   24000
Seema     32     Delhi   70000
```

So if lets say a user enters a list as below:

```
user_list = ['Age', 'City']
```

Then the Salary column would be dropped:

```
         Age      City 
Name
Stuti     28  Varanasi   
Saumya    32     Delhi   
Aaditya   25    Mumbai   
Saumya    32     Delhi   
Saumya    32     Delhi   
Saumya    32    Mumbai   
Aaditya   40  Dehradun   
Seema     32     Delhi
```

But if the list entered contains an element that does not match with the headings, the code will ask the user to enter a new list, as below:

```
>>> Please Enter columns you wish to keep: 
user_list = ['Age', 'Gender']
>>>'Gender' is not a column in df, please enter a new list!
```

Essentially, the list is always a subset of a list of column headers.
I would like to have something like this:

```
while True:
    user_list = [column for column in input('Please Enter columns you wish to keep: ').split()]
    if user_list in list(df.columns):
        # some code to drop the column that is not mentioned
        df.columns = user_list
        break
    else:
        print('try again')
```

Comment: Your last code is wrong.

Comment: @lazy i know its wrong, i just cant figure out it

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

employees = [('Stuti', 28, 'Varanasi', 20000),
            ('Saumya', 32, 'Delhi', 25000),
            ('Aaditya', 25, 'Mumbai', 40000),
            ('Saumya', 32, 'Delhi', 35000),
            ('Saumya', 32, 'Delhi', 30000),
            ('Saumya', 32, 'Mumbai', 20000),
            ('Aaditya', 40, 'Dehradun', 24000),
            ('Seema', 32, 'Delhi', 70000)
            ]

df = pd.DataFrame(employees, columns=['Name', 'Age','City', 'Salary'], )
df = df.set_index('Name')

user_list = ['Age', 'Gender']
data = df[list(set(user_list) & set(df.columns))]
if len(data):
    print(data)
else:
    print('try again')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider `user_list` as a list, and check if it's a subset for `df.columns`, in the above implementation you have decided after the first element only.

```
while True:
    user_list = [column for column in input('Please Enter columns you wish to keep: ').split()]
    if set(user_list).issubset(set(df.columns)):
        df = df[user_list]
        break
    else:
        print('try again')
print(df)
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! I am new to python, didnt know .issubset can be used like this.

Comment: [This](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/list-vs-tuple-vs-set-vs-dictionary-in-python) is a good article on basic python data structures! please don't forget to accept and upvote the answer if that was helpful @Neptune